# SQLAlchemy set a field to 1 hour in the future using func.now()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to store a future timestamp in my DB but ideally using SQLAlchemy's `func.now()` function and a timedelta. Is this possible? Something like:

```
new_obj = MyTable(event_time=(func.now() + OFFSET))
```

I can do this using `datetime.utcnow()` but it's not 100% ideal. It seems like it should be possible to do `func.now()` with an offset, and it would avoid explaining why our event and created timestamps are slightly mismatched, even if it is a sub-second difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
    timestamp = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
```

or:

```
    timestamp = func.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
```

Documentation on timedelta can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672). TL;DR - Server-side date arithmetic with `timedelta()` works with PostgreSQL and Oracle, but not with MySQL, SQL Server (mssql), or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @megshevy and Gord Thompson - I was testing something with sqlite (which saved an int) and assumed a special function was required and could not locate one. It's helpful to know this is the correct way to do this, but that it does not work for sqlite.